# In Vim, how to swap 2 non adjacent patterns?

Tags: regex, vim

I have lines of text, all with the same structure, and would like to make a permutation of 2 elements on all lines:

```
1257654 some text (which may be long) #Foo
1543098 some other text #Barbar
1238769 whatever #Baz
2456874 something else #Quux
```

I want to obtain :

```
#Foo some text (which may be long) 1257654
#Barbar some other text 1543098
#Baz whatever 1238769
#Quux something else 2456874
```

This is where I am stuck :

```
:%s/\(\d\{7\}\)\(#.\{-}\)/\2\1/
```

Where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your substitution is that you only have two groups instead of three.

Your goal is to swap `1` and `3` around `2`:

```
(1)(2)(3) --> (3)(2)(1)
```

So you need to have three groups in your pattern:

```
(1543098)( some other text )(#Barbar)
```

to be able to do:

```
(#Barbar)( some other text )(1543098)
```

This substitution seems to work:

```
:s/^\(\d\{7\}\)\(.*\)\(#\w*\)/\3\2\1
```

here is a shorter and prettier version thanks to `verymagic`:

```
:s/\v^(\d{7})(.*)(#\w*)/\3\2\1`
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution (it works beautifully) and for your explanations.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/^\(\d\{7\}\)\(.*\) \(#.*\)/\3\2 \1/
```

Might work for you.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it, but got the answer : E488: Trailing characters (I made a copy-paste). Furthermore, why is it necessary to have 3 groups when 2 patterns only are concerned ? Would it be possible to have a "Regex-forensics" to explain it ?

Comment: One group for the `1257654`, one group for the `#Foo`, another group for what's between them.

Comment: I don't think the `/` should be there between `\2/\1`, that's why you get trailing characters error.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it

```
%s/\v^(\d{7})(.{-})\s*(#.*)$/\3\2 \1/
```

Haven't checked any of the other answers yet

The non-greedy match (`{-}`) is the key here

Comment: Thank you for your solution, which works as expected. Thanks again.